# statically analysing Lua code for potential errors

Tags: lua, code-analysis, static-analysis

I'm using a closed-source application that loads Lua scripts and allows some customization through modifying these scripts. Unfortunately that application is not very good at generating useful log output (all I get is 'script failed') if something goes wrong in one of the Lua scripts.

I realize that dynamic languages are pretty much resistant to static code analysis in the way C++ code can be analyzed for example.

I was hoping though, there would be a tool that runs through a Lua script and e.g. warns about variables that have not been defined in the context of a particular script.

Essentially what I'm looking for is a tool that for a script:

```
local a
print b
```

would output:

```
warning: script.lua(1): local 'a' is not used'
warning: script.lua(2): 'b' may not be defined'
```

It can only really be warnings for most things but that would still be useful! Does such a tool exist? Or maybe a Lua IDE with a feature like that build in?

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Automated static code analysis for Lua is not an easy task in general. However, for a limited set of practical problems it is quite doable.

Quick [googling for "lua lint"](http://www.google.ru/search?q=lua+lint) yields these two tools: [lua-checker](http://code.google.com/p/lua-checker/) and [Lua lint](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaLint).

You may want to roll your own tool for your specific needs however.

[Metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/) is one of the most powerful tools for static Lua code analysis. For example, please see [metalint](http://github.com/fab13n/metalua/tree/master/src/samples/metalint), the tool for global variable usage analysis.

Please do not hesitate to post your question on [Metalua mailing list](http://lists.luaforge.net/mailman/listinfo/metalua-list). People there are usually very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [lua-inspect](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaInspect), which is based on metalua that was already mentioned. I've integrated it into [ZeroBrane Studio IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com/), which generates an output very similar to what you'd expect. See this SO answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11789348/1442917.

Answer (score 2):

For checking globals, see [this lua-l posting](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-05/msg00306.html). Checking locals is harder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a parser for lua (should be available as open source) and use it to parse the script into a proper AST tree. Use that tree and a simple variable visibility tracker to find out when a variable is or isn't defined.

Usually the scoping rules are simple:

- start with the top AST node and an empty scope
- item look at the child statements for that node. Every variable declaration should be added in the current scope.
- if a new scope is starting (for example via a { operator) create a new variable scope inheriting the variables in the current scope).
- when a scope is ending (for example via } ) remove the current child variable scope and return to the parent.
- Iterate carefully.

This will provide you with what variables are visible where inside the AST. You can use this information and if you also inspect the expressions AST nodes (read/write of variables) you can find out your information.

Comment: You probably meant not "{" and "}" (which serve as table constructor in Lua), but "do" and "end" keywords (also various control constructs like if-then-else, two kind of for loops etc.).

Comment: I have no idea how the lua language looks like :-) But i assumed it has some idea of "variable scope".
I actually did this kind of thing for Java recently.

Answer (score 1):

I just started using [`luacheck`](https://github.com/mpeterv/luacheck) and it is excellent!

The first release was from 2015.