# Lint-ing tool for Lua

Tags: lua, grammar

I have recently started doing a little Lua for Minecraft's mod, Computer Craft. I've always been hooked on javascript, and the tool I found the most useful was JS Lint. My question is, is there something like JS Lint that I can use to check my Lua scripts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Lua-Checker](https://www.ohloh.net/p/lua-checker) will get the job done for you. Another tool is [Lua Lint](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaLint)

Answer (score 9):

There is also [lua-inspect](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaInspect). I integrated it into [ZeroBrane Studio IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com) and extended the list of potential problems it reports. Here is the subset of what gets reported from one of my tests:

- inspect.lua(1): first assignment to global variable 'f'
- inspect.lua(2): first use of unknown global variable 'b'
- inspect.lua(4): unused parameter 'to' in anonymous function
- inspect.lua(8): unused local variable 'y'; consider removing or replacing with '_'
- inspect.lua(11): local variable 'y' masks earlier declaration on line 10
- inspect.lua(15): local function 'y' masks earlier declaration on line 8
- inspect.lua(17): unused local function 'test'
- inspect.lua(17): unused parameter 'x' in function 'test'
- inspect.lua(30): unused parameter 'bar' in function 'tbl.foo'