# How to print errors in lua script without running script?

Tags: c++, error-handling, lua

I'm new using Lua in C++. I have some problem with printing error of script.
My purpose is :

1. **Find errors of syntax, function name using luaL_dofile or luaL_dostring without running code** like
   build codes in Visual studio.
   (When using luaL_loadfile or luaL_loadstring, it just find syntax error like 'a == 1', but can't find function name error like 'prit(a)')
2. **Want to print all errors.**(In lua, if there was 2 or more errors, it only prints error that was occurred first)

For example I made lua script like this :

- test.lua

```
function sayHello(name)
  print("Hello, " .. name .. "!")
end

for a=0, 10

  print(a)
end

sayHello()
```

and in c++ code :

- test.cpp

```
...
int ret;

ret = luaL_dofile(LuaState, filename);
if(ret != 0) {
  cout << "error : " << lua_tostring(LuaState, -1) << endl;
  lua_pop(LuaState, 1);
}
```

I want to print errors like :

```
lua: test.lua:2: attempt to concatenate local `name' (a nil value)
lua: test.lua:7: `do' expected near `print'
```

Could anybody teach me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lint-ing tool for Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770951/lint-ing-tool-for-lua)

Comment: Only syntax errors (such as "do expected near print") are detectable without running script, use `luaL_loadfile` and `luaL_loadstring`. Runtime errors (such as "attempt to concatenate a nil value") are much harder to predict without running the script.

Comment: Because whether ot not there is a function `prit` will only become known during runtime.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff So is there any no way to find error like "attempt to concatenate a nill value" without running the script?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin I really want to find function error likes Visual studio. It find the all errors before running the code.

Comment: Search for a clever Lua linter.

Comment: Visua Studio does not detect runtime errors. It may do some static code analysis and it will compile the code but it won't know if nonsense-values cause errors on runtime. Just use a combination of the Lua compiler and a linter like luacheck like everybody else.

Comment: @Piglet Thank you for the answer. Now I'm trying to use luacheck and have a question. Could I use the luacheck in C++? I'm using luna5 and added functions written in C++, so I want luacheck works in C++ file and find error whether the function name was wrong in lua script or not.